# How to create a notification feature like facebook

Tags: notifications

I'm trying to create a notification feature in my sharepoint 2013 site. I would like it working like the facebook's way (the global icon showing the new feeds of the logged user). I've created the global icon on the top sharepoint's ribbon but I don't know the best way to do the notification system itself.

**One of my ideas:** 
Create a WebAPi Asp.Net application with a signalr hub, a event receiver to attach into the microfeed list and a client site html/js to be placed in the top ribbon.

**It'd work this way:** 
When a new item was added to the microfeed list, the event receiver calls the WebAPI with the signalr hub, and the signalr sends a message to the client with the new feed data.

**I've already checked this question out:** [Facebook-like notifications when new item is added to certain list/library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91585/facebook-like-notifications-when-new-item-is-added-to-certain-list-library)

I'd like to know if anyone knows one better way to do this process above.
**Thanks.**

Comment: would you like to share if you have implemented this functionality? I'm at same stage now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The SignalR integration and event receiver are overkill. Just query the list every 10 seconds or so in JavaScript, and use SharePoint's built in `SP.UI.Notify.addNotification` function to surface the notification.

Your proposed solution would increase the level of effort by a factor of ten and provide no additional benefit.

Even better, just query the list on page load, and forget about all the real time stuff, unless you have super-time-sensitive data or users who spend long periods of time on the same page.