# How to highlight hyperlink to SP custom list when new item appears in that list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I created a hyperlink in SharePoint 2013 webpart area which redirects to custom list in SharePoint. That custom list will contain some announcements for SharePoint users.

I need a solution to highlight (or make some sign, like little star or something) that hyperlink when new item appears in mentioned list.

Can somebody help me to achieve my goal?

Comment: What is the definition of "new item"? Do you want to highlight the hyperlink if an update appears while the user is currently on the page with the hyperlink? Or highlight the hyperlink if the user hasn't read all announcements in the list? Or some other definition?

Comment: Your both questions are appropriate to my case - I want to have highlighted hyperlink after someone adds (not updates) new item/element/record to the SP list. It should be highlighted for 1 day since emergence an item in the list (or another period of time). It should also appears while the user is currently one the page with the hyperlink.

Comment: The following might be a partial answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/92246/51055

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but these notifications disappear after clicking them - that information should lasts as long as added item is considered as "new" item. 

I need to find a solution which:
- is allowed to see by all SharePoint users,
- has a form of hyperlink/buton,
- is signed by highlight it/emergence of small sign next to hyperlink/buton.

If somebody knows such solution, I would be grateful to present it here.